# Some items doesn't display on iPad Pro

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, responsive-design

Some items doesn't display on iPad Air.

If you check this page: https://xposed-837fc.web.app/magazin-online

Under the "Profesionalism. Promptitudine. Perfectionare.", you shall find some projects with their images. But on iPad Air doesn't display.

I tested it on Chrome for all dimensions and they appear, even with the iPad Pro emulator, which has almost the same specs with the Air and it works.
But on the iPad Air doesn't.

Do someone know why?

I can't find any logical explanation

**iPad Air**

[image]

**iPar Pro Emulator from Chrome**

[image]

**Projects Map Component**

```
function ProjectsMap({ projects }) {
  const sectionData = {
    title: "Profesionalism. Promptitudine. endl Perfectionare.",
    subtitle: "PORTOFOLIU",
    description:
      "Oferim servicii de programare de inalta calitate. Fie ca vorbim de un simplu site de prezentare sau de o Aplicatie Mobila, proiectul tau are aceeasi importanta pentru noi. Facem ideea ta sa fie realitate in cel mai scurt timp posibil. Avem grija la toate detaliile proiectului tau. Produsul final va fi exact ceea ce iti doresti. Ne place sa invatam lucruri noi. In fiecare zi, ne perfectionam in ceea ce stim deja. Suntem deschisi intotdeauna la noile trenduri ale industriei si dornici sa ne adaptam.",
  }

  return (
    <div className="projects">
      <TextSection data={sectionData} />
      <div className="projects__container">
        {projects.map(project => {
          return (
            <Link
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${project.picture})` }}
              className="projects__item"
              key={project.title}>
              <div className="projects__item__overlay">
                <span>{project.title}</span>
              </div>
            </Link>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

SCSS

```
.projects {
  padding: 100px 90px;

  &__container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  &__item {
    width: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
    transition: all 1.2s;

    &:hover {
      background-size: 130%;
    }

    &__overlay {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 1;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;

      &:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        background-size: 150% !important;

        span {
          display: block;
        }
      }

      span {
        display: none;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 36px;
        text-shadow: 0px 3px 5px gray;
      }
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .projects {
    padding: 100px 30px;

    &__container {
      grid-template-columns: 100%;
    }
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .projects__item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm very sorry, I thought that using devtools would be easier for understanding the problem. I updated screenshots and the code. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`aspect-ratio` is not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio#browser_compatibility) in your version of Safari for iOS. It will be available in Version 15.

You can use [this padding trick](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) in the interim.

Comment: Thank you very much!